# OpenCL crashing while uploading large data with CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

recently I met a issue on OpenCL.
If I create a large cl::Buffer( let's say It's 1920*1080*3 bytes large) with  the flag CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR. Whenever I do a enqueueWriteBuffer, it crashes with

```
 "* ** stack smashing detected ***: bin/example1 terminated".
```

Weird enough. With CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR. It gave me error -38( CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT) on enqueueWriteBuffer. Also with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, everything is fine.

But shouldn't all three CL_MEM_COPY/USE/ALLOC_HOST_PTR does the same job to create a working buffer? Why one works and other fails? What am I missing?

Edit:
HERE IS THE SOURCE CODE(example/hugeData.cpp)

https://github.com/marty1885/EasyCL

Comment: Source code addend in edit. It's a test code to test my OpenCL library.

Comment: ohh It requires the whole reop to work.
Sorry, Give me a while to break it down.